# Why does my PHP contact form not sendin the messages

Tags: php, email

Okay so i got this form in my website and when i test it and try to send an email message it says that the message has been sent but i dong get it to my email...

here are the codes:

contact.php:

```
<?php
function ValidateEmail($email)
{
    $regex = '/([a-z0-9_.-]+)'. # name
    '@'. # at
    '([a-z0-9.-]+){1,255}'. # domain & possibly subdomains
    '.'. # period
    "([a-z]+){2,10}/i"; # domain extension 
    if($email == '') {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $eregi = preg_replace($regex, '', $email);
    }
    return empty($eregi) ? true : false;
}

include 'config.php';

error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post)
{
    $name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = stripslashes($_POST['subject']);
    $message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);
    $error = '';
    if(!$name)
    {
        $error .= '<p>Please enter your name.</p>';
    }
    if(!$email)
    {
        $error .= '<p>Please enter an e-mail address.</p>';
    }
    if($email && !ValidateEmail($email))
    {
        $error .= '<p>Please enter a valid e-mail address.</p>';
    }
    if(!$subject || strlen($subject) < 2)
    {
        $error .= "<p>Please enter the subject.</p>";
    }
    if(!$message || strlen($message) < 2)
    {
        $error .= "<p>Please enter your message.</p>";
    }
    if(!$error)
    {
        $mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $message,
             "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"
            ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
            ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
        if($mail)
        {
            echo 'OK';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<div id="notification">'.$error.'</div>';
    }
}
```

?>

config.php:

```
<?php
// Change this to your email account
define("WEBMASTER_EMAIL", 'my mail address');
```

?>

form.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#contactForm").submit(function(){
    var str = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "contact.php",
        data: str,
        success: function(msg){
            $("#note").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
                if(msg == 'OK')
                {
                    result = '<div id="notification"><p>Your message has been sent. Thank you!</p></div>';
                    $('#contactForm').each (function(){
                        this.reset();
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    result = msg;
                }
                $(this).html(result);
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

Thanks!!

Comment: ((i know i need to put my email address where it says "my email address".. i have removed it on this post.))

Comment: Was this a script that you got online?  I'm not sure why the js file is needed since you can do it all with php, even echo the alert box.

Comment: Did you configure your local email system correctly in php.ini? Are you on MS Windows? Do you use a local email server or an external relay? By the way: There is a security issue because the $name parameter enables header injection.

Comment: Okay sorry for mine stupidity but it is working!! i checked the wrong mail box. i wrote my other email in the code so that's why i didnt see it.. it's working fine.!!

Answer (score 0):

Change var str = $(this).serialize(); to data: $("#contactForm").serialize(),